# Regular Expression form {m,n} does not use upper limit

Tags: javascript, regex

My understanding was that the regexp form `a{m,n}` would match `a` at most n times. However, the following snippet does not work as I would expect (this is javascript):

```
/\{{2,2}/.exec ('df{{{df')
// [ '{{', index: 2, input: 'df{{{df' ]
```

Shouldn't it return null?

Comment: I get `["{{"]` as output which is correct. What do you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is matching the text because there are two.  That satisfies the requirements your regex specifies.  If you want to prevent extras from matching use a negative lookahead: `(?!\{)`.

```
(?:^|[^{])(\{{2,2}(?!\{))
```

Then, use the first captured group.

Edit, by the way, the the `,2` in `{2,2}` is optional in this case, since it's the same number.

Edit: Added usage example to get rid of first matched character.  (Javascript doesn't support negative lookbehind.

```
var myRegexp = /(?:^|[^{])(\{{2,2}(?!\{))/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

Comment: You can use `{2}` instead of `{2,2}`. Also, personally, I'd prefer a negative lookbehind `(?<!\{)` instead of the non-capturing group at the beginning (but that's me ;) anyhow, +1

Comment: @mhyfritz, I would also prefer a negative lookbehind, but the OP's regex flavor doesn't support them.  :-(

Comment: @agent-j: Sharp! I totally forgot about that.

Comment: @mhyfritz Negative lookbehind does not seem to work in javascript.

Comment: @agent-j So in fact, the upper limit of the {m,n} form really is never read?

Comment: @Thadee Tyl, I wouldn't say that.  You're specifying how many are valid to match.  `a{1,2}b` will match `aab` and `ab`.  `.{1,2}b` matches 'aab' in this string: `aabbbb'.  '.{1,2}` is greedy, so it matches as many as can up to 2 (but at least 1).   `.{2,3}` won't match `a`, for example.

Comment: How unfortunate! `/(?:^|[^\{])\{\{(?!\{)/.exec ('df{{{d{{f')` gives me `[ 'd{{', index: 5, input: 'df{{{d{{f' ]`, hence catching the previous character if present... Is there a way to get away with this?

Comment: @Thadee Tyl, Edit: I demonstrate how in the example.

Answer (score 3):

What your expression states is find `{{` anywhere in the string, which it will find.  If you want to find only `{{` and not `{{{` then you need to specify that you want to find:

```
/[^{]\{{2,2}[^{]/
```

In English:

[Any Character Not a `{`] followed by [Exactly 2 `{`] followed by [Any Character Not a `{`]

This will match `a{{b` but not `a{b` and not `a{{{{b`

Comment: Thanks, but I might need to match two `{` which are at the beginning or the end of the string, in which case this regexp doesn't work... nor does `/[^{]?\{{2}[^{]?/

Comment: @ThaddeeTyl: You can always use alternation: `/(^|[^{])\{{2,2}([^{]|$)/`

Comment: You can use start and end of line anchors:
`/(^|[^{])\{{2,2}($|[^{])/`

`[Beginning of string or not a { ]  [exactly 2 { ]  [End of string or not a { ]`

Answer (score 1):

It matches because it contains a substring with exactly 2 left braces.  If you want it to fail to match, you have to specify that anything outside the 2 left braces you are looking for can't be a left brace.

Answer (score 1):

That regular expression is looking for exactly two left-curly-braces (`{{`), which it finds in the string "`df{{{df`" at index 2 (immediately after the first "df").  Looks right to me.